# SQL Server Variable Value By Row (MySQL := Equivalent)

Tags: sql-server, variables, variable-assignment

I've been using MySQL for a while but I'm currently in the process of learning SQL Server and the differences therein.

In MySQL, I have used the := Assignment operator as a way to reduce the amount of code written. Take this simple example:

```
SELECT 
ps.Person_Name,
@Sales := (SELECT COUNT(*) From Sales sl Where sl.Sale_Person = ps.Person_ID) as Person_Sales,
@Target := (SELECT st.Sales_Target From Targets tg Where tg.Target_Person = ps.Person_ID) as Person_Target,
(IF(@Sales < @Target, 'You Suck', 'Well Done')) as Sales_Status
From People ps
```

The idea here is that I can displace the subqueries that make up @Sales and @Target and use the variable values in the IF statement to generate the Sales_Status for each person.

I have attempted the same situation in SQL Server with no success. I have read up a lot about variables and searched online but I haven't found anything that  demonstrates how this situation can be recreated.

My questions are:

1. Is this possible in SQL Server and if so how?
2. Is this method best practice or are there any risks?
3. Are there any more efficient or better/safer ways of doing this?

I have a good understanding of SQL but I am by no means an expert. Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still use a subquery for `Sales`, but move it into the `FROM` clause, and simply `join` for the target:

```
SELECT 
  ps.Person_Name,
  sal.Cnt as Person_Sales,
  tg.Sales_Target as Person_Target,
  IF(sal.Cnt < tg.Sales_Target, 'You Suck', 'Well Done') as Sales_Status
From People ps
inner join Targets tg
  on tg.Target_Person = ps.Person_ID
inner join (select Sale_Person,COUNT(*) as Cnt from Sales group by Sale_Person) sal
  on sal.Sale_Person = ps.Person_ID
```

Which is all plain, standard SQL so should be portable across all RDBMSs (even back to MySQL :-))

Comment: Never thought of using a join to achieve this, much cleaner and more reliable. Cheers